# Error type 3: Activity Class {…} does not exist in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging, android-manifest

Recently begun to experience this error when I try to run my android application using the Eclipse IDE, already looked at other solutions but found nothing to solve my problem. Below is the error log and my manifest file.

```
[2015-02-11 10:18:28 - PapiroSmart] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.prologica.papirosmart/.SplashScreenActivity }
[2015-02-11 10:18:28 - PapiroSmart] ActivityManager: Error type 3
[2015-02-11 10:18:28 - PapiroSmart] ActivityManager: Error: Activity class {com.prologica.papirosmart/com.prologica.papirosmart.SplashScreenActivity} does not exist.
```

**Manifest file**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.prologica.papirosmart"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- Accessing camera hardware -->
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

    <!-- Access permission to Android Folders -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- Access permission to manage network conections -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" >
    </uses-permission>

    <!-- Wi-Fi Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" >
    </uses-permission>

    <application
        android:name=".app.AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Papirosmart" >
        <activity
            android:name=".cliente.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".cliente.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:parentActivityName="cliente.LoginActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="cliente.LoginActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".cliente.ConfigActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:parentActivityName="cliente.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="cliente.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".cliente.FileChooserActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:parentActivityName="cliente.MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="cliente.MainActivity" />
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="eu.janmuller.android.simplecropimage.CropImage" />

         <provider
            android:name="InternalStorageContentProvider"
            android:authorities="eu.janmuller.android.simplecropimage.CropImage"
            android:exported="true" />

        <receiver android:name=".app.ConnectionReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".app.FileUploaderService" >
        </service>

        <receiver android:name=".app.FileUploaderReceiver" >
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".app.SynchronizeService" >
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

it says `com.prologica.papirosmart.SplashScreenActivity does not exists`

so please use the specific packagename where SplashScreenActivity  exists. supose if SplashScreenActivity  is in package a.b.c. than use the package specific details with SplashScreenActivity .

Comment: I made the change to `android: name = "com.prologica.papirosmart.cliente.SplashScreenActivity"` and wiped my project, but when trying to run the application the error still remained.